# How to measure the memory footprint of importing pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am running Python on a low memory system.

I want to know whether or not importing pandas will increase memory usage significantly.

At present I just want to import pandas so that I can use the date_range function.

Comment: Just import it and check the process's memory usage before and after?

Comment: also might be worth importing only the date range function and not the entire namespace in.

Comment: @Ginger you asked for memory consumption for `import pandas`, right? For this problem, my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/43879963/3012255 provides a script and a benchmark result.

Answer (score 3):

You may also want to use a Memory Profiler to get an idea of how much memory is allocated to your Pandas objects. There are several Python Memory Profilers you can use (a simple Google search can give you an idea). PySizer is one that I used a while ago.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use the `info()` method of `pd.DataFrame`, this will give you an idea of the memory usage.

```
In [56]: df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(5,5), columns=list('ABCDE'))

In [57]: df
Out[57]: 
          A         B         C         D         E
0  0.229201  0.145442  0.214964  0.205609  0.182592
1  0.709232  0.714943  0.983360  0.635155  0.949378
2  0.741204  0.532559  0.646229  0.649971  0.686386
3  0.073047  0.382106  0.121190  0.721732  0.146408
4  0.904605  0.115031  0.377635  0.377796  0.005747

In [58]: df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 5 columns):
A    5 non-null float64
B    5 non-null float64
C    5 non-null float64
D    5 non-null float64
E    5 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(5)
memory usage: 280.0 bytes ## <- check here!
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

@Ginger I had the exact same problem. So I set up a simple function to import pandas and used `memory-profiler`. Conclusion: around `30-36MB` of memory was used up for just importing pandas on my machine, YMMV.

Check out this post I wrote on [how much memory pandas import takes](https://asfrhn.wordpress.com/2017/05/09/how-much-memory-pandas-library-takes/) which you can use to test on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

After introducing pandas to my script and loaded dataframe with 0.8MB data, ran the script and surprised to see the memory usage got increased from 13MB to 49MB. I suspected my existing script has some memory leak and I used memory profiler to check what is consuming much memory and finally the culprit is pandas. Just import statement which loads the library into memory is taking around 30MB. Importing only specific item like (from pandas import Dataframe) didn't help much in saving memory.

**Just `import pandas` takes around 30MB memory**

Once import is done, memory of dataframe object can be checked by using `print(df.memory_usage(deep=True))` which depends on the data loaded to dataframe